# unable to determine transport target for "pino-pretty"

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to use pino library but I am getting error

My code

I created a logger.js file and imported pino from node_module and added transport of pino-pretty.

logger.js

```
   import pino from "pino";
    const logger = pino({
      transport: {
        target: "pino-pretty",
        options: {
          colorize: true,
        },
      },
    });
    export default logger;
```

I created a database file and imported pino from logger file and used info function to display my error.

database.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import logger from "./logger";
const DB_CONNECTION_STRING =
  process.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING ||
  "mongodb://localhost:27017/*******";
try {
    await mongoose.connect(DB_CONNECTION_STRING);
    logger.info("Connect to database");
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(e, "Failed to connect to database. Goodbye");
    process.exit(1);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have it installed you have to install `pino-pretty`

```
npm i pino-pretty
```

Comment: pino-pretty is discouraged as a npm dependency, command should be `npm i -D pino-pretty` to add it as a dev dependency see more [here](https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty#integration)

Answer (score 6):

You can use it as a stream if it doesn't work with the transport option:

```js
import pino from "pino";
import pretty from "pino-pretty";

const stream = pretty({
  levelFirst: true,
  colorize: true,
  ignore: "time,hostname,pid",
});

const logger = pino(
  {
    name: "MyLogger",
    level: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "debug" : "info",
  },
  stream
);

export default logger;
```

More details in the docs: https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty#usage-as-a-stream

Comment: Thanks, the error message has gone when I changed to stream, typo in "developement"

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem using it with next-pino. On local was working fine, but on deployment was throwing error:

> Error: unable to determine transport target for "pino-pretty"

So my solution was to add on my logger class the importation of pino pretty:

```
import { Logger, pino } from 'pino'
import 'pino-pretty'
```

Answer (score 0):

`pino-pretty` could be missing from your package.json, have you tried adding it as a dependency?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check the environment variable. It has to be staging or production.
The SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT or so check. I had same error.

[image]

```js
import pino, { Logger } from 'pino';
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { createWriteStream } from "pino-sentry";


dotenv.config();


function prodLogger():Logger {
    const stream = createWriteStream({ dsn: process.env.SENTRY_DSN, serverName: process.env.TENANT_NAME});

    return pino({}, stream);
}

function devLogger(): Logger {
    return pino({
        timestamp: true,
        transport: {
            target: 'pino-pretty',
            options: {
                colorize: true,
                destination: 2,
                sync: process.env.SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT === 'testing',
            },
        },
    });
}

function logger(): Logger {
    return ['production', 'staging',"develop"].includes(process.env.SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT ?? '')
        ? prodLogger()
        : devLogger();
}

export default logger();
```

Comment: Please convert your image of an error message to text.

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me

```
import pino from "pino";
import path from "path";

const logsPath = path.resolve("src", "logs");

const transport = pino.transport({
  targets: [
    {
      target: "pino/file",
      options: { destination: `${logsPath}/server.log` },
      level: process.env.PINO_LOG_LEVEL || "info",
    },
    //@ts-ignore
    {
      target: "pino-pretty",
      options: {
        colorize: true,
      },
    },
  ],
});

export const logger = pino(
  {
    level: process.env.PINO_LOG_LEVEL || "info",

    timestamp: pino.stdTimeFunctions.isoTime,
  },
  transport
);
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way seems to be to use it by piping output to the CLI tool.

So don't import it in your project, and add it to your npm scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    (...)
    "dev": "nodemon --watch src/* --exec 'node src/index.js | pino-pretty'",
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  }
```